# Что такое callback-интерфейсы и с чем их едят?

Tags: java

Изучая интерфейсы, наткнулся на такую штуку,как callbak-интерфейс. Если я правильно понял,то это интерфейс-маячок,который можно прикрутить к чему-нибудь,что будет дергать этот интерфейс в случае каких-либо изменений(например такой интерфейс можно весить на канал связи и в случае прихода сообщений выполнять какое-то действие) и он в свою очередь будет выполнять прописанные методы. Вопрос в том как его реализовывать.Примеры из туториалов,которые  я нашел в сети мне не совсем понятны. Объясните пожалуйста, как реализуется эта штука, или поделитесь ссылками на хорошие материалы по данной теме.

Comment: Для java эта тема широко освещена. Ещё есть Observer (наблюдатель). Ни одна книжка по java не обходится без Observer-а. Более древняя техника и наверное попроще. Без лишних объектов, прослоек. Прямо как вы хотите - интерфейс. А Listener предполагает передачу объекта-сообщения.

Comment: идея с Observer-ом мне понравилась,но Observer применяется наверное для масштабных проектов?к примеру у меня есть набор вебсокетных соединений. и есть одна точка,которая шлет сообщения в виде цифр. цифры собираются в коллекцию и расчитывается среднее значение,которое приходит клиентам на соккет. я хочу как-то фиксировать извмнение в коллекции,чтобы клиенты по ходу изменения коллекции получали измененное ср.значение коллекции,без обновления страницы. есть ли смысл реализовывать в таком случае этот паттерн?

Comment: Observer годится для всяких прожектов.

Comment: Тут вместо callback можно с очередью замутить. Поток, который читает из точки цифры, может вместо вызова callback, ставить цифры в очередь. Другой поток ждёт когда в этой очереди появляются цифры и рассылает дальше по сокетам.

Comment: можно,но в моем случае вебсоккетное соединение сделано на vert.x 3. там вебсоккет выступает  и  как поток чтения и как поток записи(и кидать туда еще потоки, я думаю не целесообразно),тем не менее я так и не врубился,как сделать то,что описал выше средствами данного фреймворка,потому дошел до listener'ов

Comment: Под потоком там подразумевается Thread

Comment: я понимаю,что вы имеете в виду. вот сервер, который я написал на вертексе с 2 путями для клиента http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496300/how-to-perform-readstream-and-write-stream-in-websocket-connectionusing-java-a
я подумал в данном случае передавать соединение в поток,но сейчас отошел от этой мысли. думаю,что можно сделать по-другому

Comment: Ясно. Так конечно observer проще. А то из очереди один заберёт, другим уже не достанется. Что-то придумывать надо будет.

Comment: вот я и подумал,что может какой-то listener следует подвесить.сейчас задумался над реализацией observer-a.спасибо за подсказку;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

callback - обратный вызов - понятие и применение очень широкое.
callback-и вроде вашего маячка называют listener-ами(слушателями по-нашему). Они регистрируются функцией регистрации и потом вызываются не понятно кем и не известно когда (наступит событие или нет? когда? кто знает...)

Есть и другие виды callback-ов.

Например в Win32 APIесть функция `EnumWindows` для перечисления открытых окошек. Она принимает в качестве параметра функцию обратного вызова `EnumWindowsProc`.
`EnumWindows` знает что вам нужны эти окошки, но не знает зачем. 
Кроме того по каким-то важным причинам она не хочет выдавать Вам сразу готовый список.
Но с помощью callback она сдаст всех по-одному. Для каждого обнаруженного окошка вызывается Ваша функция `EnumWindowsProc`, чтобы в ней Вы сами разобрались с этим окошком. И здесь функция callback если будет вызвана, то только во время работы `EnumWindows`, а не когда-нибудь потом.

Answer (score 0):

Оффтопик для демонстрации идеи с очередью.

Вот немного переделанный пример про `BlockingQueue` из `Javadoc`:
Один `thread` в бесконечном цикле вставляет в очередь, другой извлекает. Читатель чисел практически не блокируется (только на время вызова `queue.take()`). `Observer` или любой другой `callback` заставит его ждать пока не завершится этот самый `callback`, прежде чем приступить к чтению следующего числа.

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
    public void run() {
       try {
          while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
    }
    Number produce() { 
        // читает из точки очередное число 
        // или столько сколько нужно для вычисления среднего и возвращает его
        Number x = ...;
        return x;
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
    }
    void consume(Number x) { 
        // рассылает число по сокетам
    }
}

class Setup {
    void main() {
        BlockingQueue<Number> q = new SomeQueueImplementation();
        Producer p = new Producer(q);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer(q);
        new Thread(p).start();
        new Thread(c1).start();
        new Thread(c2).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде этот ответ не имеет  прямого отношения к вопросу. Стоит либо оформить это в отдельный вопрос, либо слить с основным ответом в качестве контрпримера, либо залить на pastebin и отдать ТС.